# Image.show() doesn't display image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to display an image on VScode using Image.show from the pillow library but it doesn't work.

This is the code:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("/workspaces/105456256/project/before2.jpg")
im.show()
```

when I run this I don't get any error, instead, nothing happens.
My OS is Windows 11.
I tried the same code on PyCharm and it worked just fine.

Comment: running from the command line? if so Windows will destroy the image window as fast as it creates it, you all have to put some mechanism to pause the script until a key is pressed

Comment: Can you maybe explain this a bit further please?

Comment: You mentioned it runs OK from PyCharm so how else are you executing the code? are you double cliking it in a folder? are you calling by name from a command line terminal?

Comment: Basically, once your code completes running in the command line (terminal inside vscode in this case), it would exit immediately before you can see the picture being shown. Try to `import time` and add a `time.sleep(second)` (change second to how long you want it to sleep for) and run the code again.

Comment: @DrBwts Yes, I am running it from the terminal on Vscode. While on Pycharm I am using the run button.

Comment: @Ping34 thank you, I understand the problem now...but I tried your solution and it still doesn't work. Do I have to implement some sort of while loop maybe?

Comment: You can try to let it `while true` after the `im.show` and then once the image is shown you can `Ctrl+C` to quit the program for now. If this doesn't work then maybe it is something else to do with what program the `im.show` passes the image to.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("/workspaces/105456256/project/before2.jpg")
im.show()

input("Press ENTER to exit") # pause
```